# How to make UI layout not scale when window is resized

Tags: user-interface, actionscript-3, flash

I am working in a player and when am trying to make it fullscreen the scrubber and volume bar everything become too big in size.

How can I make it normal?

Comment: why i cant make it as mormal?!

Comment: means i cant make it same as minimized one. the symbols r looking very thin in normal mode when it goes to full screnn it all become very big. Please refer this url

http://208.43.86.106:8081/Onlinemovie/Video.php?v=dc7568bb91d203a&share=vod

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the [scaleMode](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00002154.html) of your movie and [align](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00002154.html) it to the top-left.

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

Comment: Thanks man, i tried with this line and it is not taking.
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;

now i will try with your answer.